# Хранение данных в приложении

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, парсер

В приложении должны быть текстовые данные. Пробовал хранить данные в xml, но после того как я их распарсил выводиться сплошной текст без обзацев, табуляций и т.п. 
В каком формате еще можно хранить данные в приложении, чтобы отображался на экране в нормальном виде?

Comment: Что именно за текстовые данные, их много? Они приходят откуда-то или изначально имеются и просто отображаются?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите хранить данные в приложении iOS, лучше всего использовать SQLite (Core Data) или Realm (он проще для новичка, чем Core Data).
Соответственно вы сможете хранить текст в виде NSString.

Могу предложить еще альтернативный вариант, если у вас не очень много данных. Вы можете хранить текст прямо в NSUserDefaults.
Например вот так:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(text_my_book, forKey: "book1")
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "book1")!)")
```

Comment: Realm не SQL DB и имеет собственный формат бинарного файла.
Despite popular opinion, Realm isn’t a wrapper for SQLite and doesn’t touch SQLite files on disk. Realm is a completely proprietary standard, written in C++ that is then exposed to developers via a number of different public API libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Если данных не много, можно просто выводить их файл (сериализовать). Например, NSArray  и NSDictionary имеют собственные методы записи и восстановления в\из файла

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path 
     atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile;
- (NSArray<ObjectType> *)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path;
```

В случае массивов(или словарей) языка Swift ситуация выглядит чуть хуже, но можно использовать plist формат (xml) и пользоваться

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(yourArray, toFile: filePath)
```

и распаковать

```
let restoredArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile path:filePath)
```

ничего специально парсить не придется

Answer (score 0):

Храни их в JSON. Будет удобно!

Comment: Бред какой-то вы написали. JSON достаточно удобный формат для хранения данных.

Comment: а как создать файл json? просто меняется расширение textfield-а на *.json и потом закидывается в проект?

Answer (score 0):

Для хранения текстовой информации отлично подойдет JSON и Plist файл. Все зависит от того как вы их хотите читать.

Plist файл можно распарсить в Dictionary, вообщем как и JSON, но если хардкодить данные то мне больше нравиться плист т.к. приятный интерфейс работы с ним.